# How to zip each individual element from two lists into one list using OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml, pairing

If I have an input of a tuple containing two lists of integers of the same length, and I want my output to be a list of these two lists zipped, after extracting these two lists from the tuple how do I zip each individual element into one list? For example, if my input is twolists= ([1;2;3], [4;5;6]), then I want my output to be [(1,4); (2,5); (3,6)]. How do I zip each element and add it to my output? 
The function name and type is as follows:

```
let rec pairlists twolists = ...

val pairlists : 'a list * 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list = fun
```

So far I have:

```
let rec pairlists twolists = 
  let (l1, l2) = twolists in
  let rec zip (l1,l2) =
    match l1 with 
    |[] -> l2
    |x :: xs -> x :: zip(l2, xs) in
  twolists ;;
```

but this is clearly not doing what I want.

Comment: to markup a fragment of text as code, just select it with mouse and click on the button, that looks lik `{}` in the editor's window.

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for [List.combine](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/libref/List.html#VALcombine) ?

> val combine : 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list
>
> Transform a pair of lists into a list of pairs: combine [a1; ...; an] [b1; ...; bn] is [(a1,b1); ...; (an,bn)].
>
> Raises Invalid_argument if the two lists have different lengths. Not tail-recursive.

Answer (score 1):

If your result list should contain elements that consist of the elements of both sublists, then you obviously have to destructure each sublist on each iteration.

If the lists are guaranteed to have the same lengths, the solution can be as simple as:

```
let rec zip paired_lists =
  match paired_lists with
  | [], [] -> []
  | h1::t1, h2::t2 -> (h1, h2)::(zip (t1, t2))
  | _, _ -> failwith "oops, the lists seems to have different lengths"
;;

zip ([1;2;3], [4;5;6]);;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 6)]
```

But this one is not tail-recursive, which is obviously not good. The second sub-optimal thing is this reconstruction of tuple of lists on each iteration (I'm a newbie in OCaml, so chances are compiler is smart enough to avoid the unnecessary allocations, but still...). Fixing both flaws is trivial too:

```
let zip_tr paired_lists =
  let list1, list2 = paired_lists in
  let rec aux l1 l2 acc =
    match l1, l2 with
    | [], [] -> List.rev acc
    | h1::t1, h2::t2 -> aux t1 t2 (h1, h2)::acc
    | _, _ -> failwith "oops, the lists seems to have different lengths"
  in aux list1 list2 []
;;

zip_tr ([1;2;3], [4;5;6]);;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your code does not match the expected signature :

```
line 2, characters 11-13:
Warning 26: unused variable l2.
Line 2, characters 7-9:
Warning 26: unused variable l1.
val pairlists : 'a list * 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
```

Indeed, both possible matches return either a `'a list` (this is l2) or `x::zip...` which is also a list of `'a` type.

There should be sth like `(x,y)::list` in your code.

In addition, `pairlists` is not recursive and does not need to be declared as such, only `zip` is recursive.
The end of your function shall be like this (otherwise zip has no effect) :

```
....
let rec zip (l1,l2) =
match l1 with 
|[] -> l2
|x :: xs -> x :: zip(l2, xs) in
zip twolists ;;
```

Comment: If I wanted pairlists to be recursive, how would I structure my code? (I don't need to necessarily use the zip function).

Comment: `zip` is sufficient, just rename it to `pairlists` and that's it (you do not need auxiliary function in your case).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other solutions mentioned, ocaml-4.08 onwards enables you to provide let+ and and+ operators which will zip a list sum-wise, where you might otherwise think of using applicatives.  Whether it is an improvement on them is in the eye of the beholder:

```
let (let+) list f = List.map f list

let (and+) a b =
  let rec loop first second =
    match first,second with
      first_hd::first_tl,second_hd::second_tl ->
       (first_hd,second_hd)::(loop first_tl second_tl)
    | _ -> []
  in
  loop a b

let pairlists = function
    first,second ->
     let+ elt1 = first
     and+ elt2 = second in
     [elt1 ; elt2]

(* example *)
let () =
  let res = pairlists ([1;2;3], [4;5;6]) in
  List.iter
    (fun list -> List.iter (fun i -> Printf.printf "%d " i) list ;
                 print_endline "")
    res
```

Here by way of comparison is the more traditional approach if you are using applicatives

```
let pure x = [x]

let (<*>) aps args =
  List.concat (List.map (fun f -> List.map (fun x -> f x) args) aps)

let (<|>) aps args =
  let rec loop args_rest aps_rest =
    match args_rest,aps_rest with
      args_hd::args_tl,aps_hd::aps_tl ->
       (aps_hd args_hd)::(loop args_tl aps_tl)
    | _ -> []
  in
  loop args aps

let pairlists = function
    first,second ->
     let two_list a b = a :: [b] in
     pure two_list <*> first <|> second

(* example *)
let () =
  let res = pairlists ([1;2;3], [4;5;6]) in
  List.iter
    (fun list -> List.iter (fun i -> Printf.printf "%d " i) list ;
                 print_endline "")
    res
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach to this which is lazy and tail-recursive uses [sequences](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html).

```
# let rec seq_pairs lst1 lst2 () =
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | [], [] -> Seq.Nil
    | x::xs, y::ys -> Seq.Cons ((x, y), seq_pairs xs ys)
    | _, _ -> invalid_arg "lengths don't match";;
val seq_pairs : 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) Seq.t = <fun>
# List.of_seq @@ seq_pairs [1; 2; 3] [4; 5; 6];;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 6)]
```